# Angular project i can not find folder "appmodule.ts"

Tags: angular, angular-material, find

[Angular 15 CRUD app using material UI | JSON-server | step by step](https://youtu.be/4mKY_yDq64g?si=GtrnLG1rI5h8FFGQ) watching this video on 6:15 second i can't find folder app.module.ts in folder src --> app --> (appmodule.ts) ? how can i find this ? or how can i add library "icon"

i try add library "icons" on app.components.ts but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons why you aren't finding your Angular modules. According to [Angular Architects](https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/angulars-future-without-ngmodules-lightweight-solutions-on-top-of-standalone-components/), angular is meant not to have modules in the future at all. Maybe you've found that the commands you are using in your local Angular CLI are meant for a newer version that doesn't create the modules, contrary to the previous version of the tutorial you're watching.

The solution goes to learning how to use 'standalone' components, which in short terms means that whatever was in the Angular Modules is now specified at the `@Component` decorator.

Something like this:

```
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatToolbarModule]
})
export class AppComponent {
    ...
}
```

So, if you see them adding anything to a module in the tutorials, just add it to that same field at the corresponding `@Component` decorator, in this case it's at the imports array.

Greetings.